# Blender 2.80 Spin

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to use the spin command in Blender 2.80. However, I cannot seem to make it work. All it does it add faces to the inside of the object I am trying to spin. 
I've tried add a sequence of images so I can show what is happening, but I am unable to work out how to add more than one image. So, here is the final image of an attempt to spin on the Z axis.[image: final image]

Hope somebody can put me right, please.

Cheers 
Dave

Comment: Delete all the faces so only the edges are left, then spin it.

Comment: Sorry For the delay in responding. Thanks Rob.